# GPUImageView inside SKScene as SKNode material - Playing transparent video on ARKit

Tags: gpuimage, arkit, skscene

In Project -A- I used GPUImageView to display Video (recorded on greenscreen) with transparency. Using the GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, and so on.
and works Superb.

Another project -B- based on ARKIT shows me in the space a plain with VIDEO and it also works fine using SKVideoNode and AVPlayer.

Now the question is to combine it all together in one :) So in space I want to display Video but with transparency ...
Unfortunately, I can not render a GPUImageView on any SpriteKit element, and then add to SKScene, which is an animated texture for SCNPlane,  is it possible at all? Or maybe there is other way to render Video with transparencies with ARKit.?

Thx for any suggestions

Comment: any progress on this issue yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task! See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680171/color-keying-video-with-gpuimage-on-a-scnplane-in-arkit/47719192#47719192).

I basically implemented [ChromaKeyMaterial](https://github.com/2RKowski/SceneKitTransparentVideo/blob/master/SceneKitTransparentVideo/Materials/ChromaKeyMaterial.swift) from [Lësha Turkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6192057/l%C3%ABsha-turkowski) and wrote this code to place and play the video.

```
import UIKit
import ARKit

class ARTransVC: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var arSceneView: ARSCNView!
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

private var player: AVPlayer = {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "FY3A4278", withExtension: "mp4") else { fatalError() }
    return AVPlayer(url: url)
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.arSceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin, ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
    self.arSceneView.session.run(configuration)

    //a delay for ARKit to capture the surroundings
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {

        // A SpriteKit scene to contain the SpriteKit video node
        let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: self.arSceneView.frame.width, height: self.arSceneView.frame.height))
        spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
        spriteKitScene.backgroundColor = .clear
        spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

        //Create the SpriteKit video node, containing the video player
        let videoSpriteKitNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: self.player)
        videoSpriteKitNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2.0, y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2.0)
        videoSpriteKitNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
        videoSpriteKitNode.yScale = -1.0
        videoSpriteKitNode.play()
        spriteKitScene.addChild(videoSpriteKitNode)

        // To make the video loop
        self.player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(ARTransVC.playerItemDidReachEnd),
            name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
            object:  self.player.currentItem)

        // Create the SceneKit scene
        let scene = SCNScene()
        self.arSceneView.scene = scene

        //Create a SceneKit plane and add the SpriteKit scene as its material
        let background = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(1), height: CGFloat(1))
        background.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
        let chromaKeyMaterial = ChromaKeyMaterial()
        chromaKeyMaterial.diffuse.contents = self.player

        let backgroundNode = SCNNode(geometry: background)
        backgroundNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        backgroundNode.geometry!.materials = [chromaKeyMaterial]

        backgroundNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-2.0)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(backgroundNode)

        //video does not start without delaying the player
        //playing the video before just results in [SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.player.seek(to:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1000))
            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
        playerItem.seek(to: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems like we're trying to do similar things, and followed some of the same tips online :). I have adapted your transparent video resolution into my own sprite/scene/ar kit code but I get this error when the video is supposed to show up: `[SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef) ` Here is my code: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/eisenbruch/yez4yK    any help would be greatly appreciated!