# ChromaKey video in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to chroma key a video in ARKit, and I have done very similar to what @Felix has done here: [GPUImageView inside SKScene as SKNode material - Playing transparent video on ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265467/gpuimageview-inside-skscene-as-sknode-material-playing-transparent-video-on-ar)

But, when the video is supposed to show up (in this case, when an AR reference image is detected) I get a `[SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)` error and the video no longer plays. It did play before I implemented the `chromaKeyMaterial`. Here is my code, starting from just after the AR refernce image is detected:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "wigz", ofType: "mp4")
let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

let spriteKitScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 640, height: 480))
let videoSpriteKitNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
let videoNode = SCNNode()
videoNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
              height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
videoNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi/2, 0, 0)

// Use spritekit with videonode inside
spriteKitScene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
videoSpriteKitNode.position = CGPoint(x: spriteKitScene.size.width / 2,
                      y: spriteKitScene.size.height / 2)
videoSpriteKitNode.size = spriteKitScene.size
videoSpriteKitNode.yScale = -1.0
videoSpriteKitNode.play()

// Loop video
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
    player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    player.play()
}

spriteKitScene.addChild(videoSpriteKitNode)

videoNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = spriteKitScene
videoNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
let chromaKeyMaterial = ChromaKeyMaterial()
chromaKeyMaterial.diffuse.contents = player
videoNode.geometry!.materials = [chromaKeyMaterial]

node.addChildNode(videoNode)

self.imageDetectView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

In the ChromaKeyMaterial.swift file, i have changed these lines to:

```
float maskY = 0.0 * c_colorToReplace.r + 1.0 * c_colorToReplace.g + 0.0 * c_colorToReplace.b;
float maskCr = 0.7132 * (c_colorToReplace.r - maskY);
float maskCb = 0.5647 * (c_colorToReplace.b - maskY);

float Y = 0.0 * textureColor.r + 1.0 * textureColor.g + 0.0 * textureColor.b;
float Cr = 0.7132 * (textureColor.r - Y);
float Cb = 0.5647 * (textureColor.b - Y);
```

In an effort to chroma key out a pure green, but I am not sure if that is the correct approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that in recent versions of SceneKit using a `SKScene` and a `SKVideoNode` is not necessary. You can directly set the `AVPlayer` as the contents of a `SCNMaterialProperty` instance.

Comment: @mnuages intersting! I will check that out! thank you.

Comment: @mnuages wow. much simpler and it seems to run better, although that could be my memory failing me or placebo. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this out. I was setting my color to key out incorrectly (and even in the wrong place *facepalm*) and there seems to be a bug that prevents the video from playing unless you delay it a bit. That bug was supposedly fixed but it seems to not be the case.

Here is my corrected and cleaned up code if anyone is interested (EDITED TO INCLUDE TIP FROM @mnuages) :

```
// Get Video URL and create AV Player
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "VIDEO_FILE_NAME", ofType: "VIDEO_FILE_EXTENSION")
let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

// Create SceneKit videoNode to hold the spritekit scene.
let videoNode = SCNNode()

// Set geometry of the SceneKit node to be a plane, and rotate it to be flat with the image
videoNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
              height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
videoNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi/2, 0, 0)

//Set the video AVPlayer as the contents of the video node's material.
videoNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = player
videoNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true

// Alpha transparancy stuff
let chromaKeyMaterial = ChromaKeyMaterial()
chromaKeyMaterial.diffuse.contents = player
videoNode.geometry!.materials = [chromaKeyMaterial]

//video does not start without delaying the player
//playing the video before just results in [SceneKit] Error: Cannot get pixel buffer (CVPixelBufferRef)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.001) {
    player.seek(to:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1000))
    player.play()
}
// Loop video
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem, queue: .main) { _ in
    player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    player.play()
}

// Add videoNode to ARAnchor
node.addChildNode(videoNode)

// Add ARAnchor node to the root node of the scene
self.imageDetectView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

And here is the chrome key material

```
import SceneKit

public class ChromaKeyMaterial: SCNMaterial {

public var backgroundColor: UIColor {
    didSet { didSetBackgroundColor() }
}

public var thresholdSensitivity: Float {
    didSet { didSetThresholdSensitivity() }
}

public var smoothing: Float  {
    didSet { didSetSmoothing() }
}

public init(backgroundColor: UIColor = .green, thresholdSensitivity: Float = 0.50, smoothing: Float = 0.001) {

    self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    self.thresholdSensitivity = thresholdSensitivity
    self.smoothing = smoothing

    super.init()

    didSetBackgroundColor()
    didSetThresholdSensitivity()
    didSetSmoothing()

    // chroma key shader is based on GPUImage
    // https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageChromaKeyFilter.m

    let surfaceShader =
    """
uniform vec3 c_colorToReplace;
uniform float c_thresholdSensitivity;
uniform float c_smoothing;

#pragma transparent
#pragma body

vec3 textureColor = _surface.diffuse.rgb;

float maskY = 0.2989 * c_colorToReplace.r + 0.5866 * c_colorToReplace.g + 0.1145 * c_colorToReplace.b;
float maskCr = 0.7132 * (c_colorToReplace.r - maskY);
float maskCb = 0.5647 * (c_colorToReplace.b - maskY);

float Y = 0.2989 * textureColor.r + 0.5866 * textureColor.g + 0.1145 * textureColor.b;
float Cr = 0.7132 * (textureColor.r - Y);
float Cb = 0.5647 * (textureColor.b - Y);

float blendValue = smoothstep(c_thresholdSensitivity, c_thresholdSensitivity + c_smoothing, distance(vec2(Cr, Cb), vec2(maskCr, maskCb)));

float a = blendValue;
_surface.transparent.a = a;
"""

    //_surface.transparent.a = a;

    shaderModifiers = [
        .surface: surfaceShader,
    ]
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

//setting background color to be keyed out
private func didSetBackgroundColor() {
    //getting pixel from background color
    //let rgb = backgroundColor.cgColor.components!.map{Float($0)}
    //let vector = SCNVector3(x: rgb[0], y: rgb[1], z: rgb[2])
    let vector = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0)
    setValue(vector, forKey: "c_colorToReplace")
}

private func didSetSmoothing() {
    setValue(smoothing, forKey: "c_smoothing")
}

private func didSetThresholdSensitivity() {
    setValue(thresholdSensitivity, forKey: "c_thresholdSensitivity")
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you show me how to initialize "node" and "imageAnchor"?

Answer (score 1):

## Using RealityKit 2 - iOS14

I believe with RealityKit you would need to use metal to create a chroma shader.
I do not know much about metal yet and cannot say how to create it but I found another way to play chroma key videos in AR with RealityKit.

From iOS14 it is possible to use a videomaterial as texture of a `ModelEntity`.

For chroma some additional steps are needed:

- First we need to convert the video asset and remove the chroma key.
- then we load this asset in the player and use the new videomaterial property of the modelEntity (iOS 14)

We start importing this incredible package by Yu Ao.
https://github.com/MetalPetal/MetalPetal/issues/289

Don't forget to import the package: `import MetalPetal`

This is the code:

```swift
// in the viewmodel you process the asset and create the player
let context = try! MTIContext(device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!)
let chromaKeyBlendFilter = MTIChromaKeyBlendFilter()
let color = MTIColor(red: 0.998, green: 0.0, blue: 0.996, alpha: 1)
//let backgroundColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
let backgroundColor = MTIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
chromaKeyBlendFilter.color = color
chromaKeyBlendFilter.smoothing = 0.001
chromaKeyBlendFilter.thresholdSensitivity = 0.4//0.475
chromaKeyBlendFilter.inputBackgroundImage = MTIImage(color: backgroundColor, sRGB: false, size: videoSize)
let composition = MTIVideoComposition(asset: asset, context: context, queue: DispatchQueue.main, filter: { request in
    guard let sourceImage = request.anySourceImage else {
        return MTIImage(color: backgroundColor, sRGB: false, size: videoSize)
    }
    return FilterGraph.makeImage(builder: { output in
        sourceImage => chromaKeyBlendFilter.inputPorts.inputImage
        chromaKeyBlendFilter => output
    })!
})

videoPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
videoPlayerItem.videoComposition = composition.makeAVVideoComposition()

let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoPlayerItem)
player.volume = 0.5
// player.play()
```

We can use the video textures in RealityKit 2.0 (Xcode 12 and iOS 14).  [See this answer by Andy Jazz here about how to set it up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59939479/9497800)

Comment: This filter removes white color also, can you advice any adjustment to avoid this issue?

Comment: I was not aware of this and I don't really know right now. The animation movie I used did not have white colors and I did not test it in that way. Maybe the best is to open an issue with the package maintainer on GitHub. He did help me and other people a lot and usually replies quite quickly.

Comment: @multitudes did you get this working using RealityKit? I've tried your answer and also implemented the MetalPetal example but no luck. Works fine using AVPlayer but when I try to render it with RealityKit I get a black background. Tips would be awesome! :)